# Set width and height for image - PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

it can be simple and stupid question but I'm new here! how I can set width and height for image? I'm using Laravel.

```
<!-- header logo start -->
<div class="header-logo">
    <inertia-link :href="route('home')">
        <img class="main-logo" v-if="logo" :src="logo" />
        <img class="main-logo" v-else :src="route('home') + '/images/logo.png'" />
    </inertia-link>
</div>
```

Comment: add this attribute to every img element `style="width:100px;height:100px"`

Answer (score 1):

As you can review on the [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) website it is possible to set this in the  tag:

```
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks from @Amir-Khaledian

```
<!-- header logo start -->
<div class="header-logo">
<inertia-link :href="route('home')">
    <img class="main-logo" v-if="logo" :src="logo" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
    <img class="main-logo" v-else :src="route('home') + '/images/logo.png'" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
</inertia-link>
```

Comment: Welcome @Zed-Zand. Nice to read, that the suggested change worked. But instead of answering your own question you should give Amir Khaledian the opportunity to answer your question, so you can accept it. This way Amir Khaledian can earn the reputation he deserves.